# Is a dsPIC33 suitable for creating a 40 kHz signal with 16 bits of resolution as input for ultrasonic transducers?

Tags: pic, dac, transducer

I'm trying to build a parametric speaker (Directional speaker) that could output a somewhat decent and high-quality sound hence why I'm aiming for a 16-bit resolution.

The audio signal needs to be amplitude modulated to 40kHz as a single channel input for an array of ultrasonic transducers.

The [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70292G.pdf) (p. 277, section 22.1) states that the Audio DAC is capable of

- 16-bit resolution (14-bit accuracy)
- 100 ksps Maximum Sampling Rate

The two questions I have are:

1. **Considering these characteristics, is a 40 kHz signal output even possible with this DAC?**

The "Note" - on the same page- says:

> The DAC module is designed specifically
> for audio applications and is not
> recommended for control type
> applications.

This especially threw me off since I suppose a 40 kHz signal technically isn't considered audio although it isn't considered control type either.

2. **Even if possible, is a dsPIC33 even an appropriate microcontroller for this purpose?**

Comment: Doesn’t make sense to use that instead of a high Q sine oscillator. What specs?

Comment: "somewhat decent and high-quality sound" isn't really much of a spec. What does the waveform look like? Sine? Square? Some series of pulses? Something else? How much deviation from the 'perfect' waveform is acceptable (hint: "as little as possible" also isn't a spec).

Comment: You probably need to provide us with a nice tutorial on parametric speakers and the key ideas that make them work the way you want them to. They can be used in phased arrays for directivity, as well. So if you have that as a goal, say so and say how. Most of us don't have a doctorate in the non-linearity behaviors of air and ultrasound propagation that create differences, sums, and higher harmonics from piezos. (Obviously, the goal is the difference since that's what we can hear.) We need an education from you before we can offer helpful thoughts. Just saying.

Comment: @brhans As I mentioned the input is an audio waveform (could be analog or digital) and the output is the AM modulated of that signal over a 40 kHz sine carrier. As for the specs, frankly, I don't know which specs you're exactly looking for and even if I did know, unfortunately, I wouldn't be able to give you any details as I'm still in the very early stages of research and I'm just exploring different techniques for the modulation and wanted to see if a dsPIC33 is a suitable choice for this purpose.

Comment: @jonk I can assure you I don't have a doctorate either and my only knowledge of this tech are from a few papers and videos. The basic idea is that the audio waveform is modulated over a 40 kHz sine wave and output by an array of ultrasonic transducers before amplification. Here's a video of someone making one using PWM with a simple STM32 MCU. https://youtu.be/9hD5FPVSsV0 And here's a great paper exploring different methods and different implementations (Analog, DSP, FPGA, PWM) of modulation https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0003682X12000904